# Probability with inequality condition

Tags: probability, inequality

[image]

Can someone explain how to solve this problem. Since I can get 7 integers from 1st inequality 5 integers from 2nd inequality I got total number of cases of 35. Then I counted the possibilities that would be less than 4. For example x=o y can = 0, 1, 2, 3, when x=1 y=0,1,2 and so on. I came down to 10/35, but the answer is 1/3 .

Comment: This problem isn't very clear. Are $x$ and $y$ supposed to be random variables? If so, what are their distributions?

Comment: Sorry, that was all I was given. I believe they don't have any distribution and that they're integers.

Comment: Can you first confirm that $x$ and $y$ are integers, not just real numbers? This makes a difference.

Comment: The answer is $\frac{1}{3}$ if they're real numbers with uniform distribution. (A four by six rectangle has area 24, the right triangle cut off by $x+y < 4$ and $x,y \geq 0$, with side lengths four and four, has area 8.)

Comment: Confirmed they are real numbers with uniform dist. aes, could you explain further? not sure how you got side lengths four and four.

Comment: @aes Do you want to type this out as an answer (complete with the graphical sketch)? Anyway, a brief explanation for the OP, sketch the line $x+y = 4$. Now consider the vertical line $x = 6$ and the horizontal line $y = 4$. Can you see the required probability as a ratio of areas? Also, it's never wise to assume extra constraints e.g. variables are integers, unless you're explicitly allowed to make those assumptions.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a six by four rectangle, representing the possible values of $x$ and $y$. Choosing $x$ and $y$ [uniformly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(continuous)) and [independently](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)) means choosing a random point in this rectangle, with the probability it's in a given region proportional to the area of that region.

[image]

I've drawn a line $x+y = 4$. The values you're interested in are below that line.

The total area is 24, and the area of the triangle below $x+y=4$ is $8$.

Thus the probability that $x+y < 4$ is $\frac{8}{24} = \frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: x+y=4 y=-x+4 so 4=y-intercept and x has slope of -1/1. Makes perfect sense. The answer with the visual was very helpful. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: @GMATnoob Certainly. Also, you could look at $x+y=4$ differently: both $(4,0)$ and $(0,4)$ are solutions, and it's linear, so the line is the line through those two points.